# Integration by subsitution

Tags: integration, substitution

[image]

Im confused by the subsitution, I would've assumed it would be

[image]

I can give more context if needed, its from the paper. On the generality of the relationship among contact stiffness,
contact area, and elastic modulus during indentation

Comment: There must be a misprint, unless $P=0$, since the integral is $a$-independent.

Comment: This looks like a mistake. Maybe contact the author if possible?